# How do I log the size of my Bundle in Mb?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, parcelable, android-bundle

I sometimes get `TransactionTooLargeException` in `onSaveInstanceState`. So, I'm assuming that the size of my `Bundle` being too large is causing this. I'd like to log its exact/approx size so I can get a rough estimate of the amount I need to minimize it by.

Right now, the only way I can find its size is when the `TransactionTooLargeException` is thrown with

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1026104)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
I/art: Compiler allocated 6MB to compile void com.example.ExampleModel.writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel, int)
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1026104 bytes
```

Comment: I think you're attacking the problem from the wrong direction.  Why do you have so much data to save?  Bundle sizes should rarely go over a few K.  Most likely you're storing things that should go in files (like images) or databases (like large parsed network responses).

Comment: I totally agree with you. I was just curious if there was a way to log its size.

Comment: You could write it to a Parcel then marshall the Parcel, which will return a byte[] of the contents.  The take the size of that.

Comment: You aren't using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` by any chance, are you? https://android.jlelse.eu/rip-transactiontoolargeexception-7256cf14cd69

Comment: Maybe too late, but You can try this https://github.com/guardian/toolargetool

Comment: That looks exactly like what I was looking for. You can post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

[please click here for reference](https://medium.com/google-developers/faster-android-studio-builds-with-dex-in-process-5988ed8aa37e)

To take advantage of Dex In Process, you’ll need to modify your gradle.properties file and increase the amount of memory allocated to the Gradle Daemon VM by 1 Gb, to a minimum of 2 Gb, using the org.gradle.jvmargs property:

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m